# Logical left shift of 0

Tags: logical-operators, bit-shift

Here my question is why the logical left shift 0 is one. 
1<<0 = 1, but how?

According to definition the logical left shift works by shifting the bits towards left by n bits.

Logical left shifts works by multiplying number with 2
n << number = 2*n*number; not in case of number=0;

Even if the 0 or the negative numbers are stored in two's complement, so for zero all the bits must be one, then how its logical left shift works.

```
1<<0 =1         1<<2=4
2<<0 =2         2<<2=8
3<<0 =3         3<<2=12
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bit shift left multiplies the right hand number by 2 to the power of the left hand side.  For example: `1 << 2` is the same as `1 * 2^2` (where `^` represents exponent, not XOR).

1 in binary is `0001`, then bitshifting it by 0 won't do anything, which aligns with what you observed.

So any number `x << 0` is equivalent to `x * 2^0`, which is `x * 1`, which is just `x`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Can you please resolve one more doubt about the logical left shift of -1, how its calculated.  i.e.  1<<-1

Comment: @SoniaBehal that's undefined behavior i.e. there is no standard way for a compiler to interpret negative shift amounts.  For example, gcc on my computer says its zero, but clang spits out random numbers.  Both of them print warnings as well.

Comment: "Bit shift left multiplies the right hand number by 2 to the power of the left hand side" isn't that backwards?

Answer (score 0):

you are doing a mistake by considering it "2 * n" but its "2^n". like 2*3=6 but 2^3 will be 8. secondly, if you have 0001 and you are shifting 0-bit than it wouldn't affect because 2^0=1 and 1*1 will be 1. but if you shift 1-bit it will multiply it with "2". for example, 0001 and you shifted 1-bit. it becomes 0010 which is 2.